# How do I copy rows from one table to another in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have been trying to copy the data listed in one table to another that are both located in the same database.  However, every time I have everything entered, it runs the query and says 0 rows updated.

I have tried several variations in an attempt to get this to work.  One such attempt is as listed below.  I found this while researching in an attempt to get this done.

```
UPDATE 
     t1
SET 
     t1.column = t2.column
FROM 
     Table1 t1 
     INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
     ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` will only modify records that already exist, if you want to insert rows that exist on another table use `INSERT`.

You can combine `INSERT` and `SELECT` to copy a whole `table1` into a `table2`.

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1;
```

You can use `INSERT IGNORE` to copy only records that don't exist yet (based on unique keys).

You can also specify fields to copy in case the tables are different:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, first_name, last_name) SELECT id, name, surname FROM table1;
```